# Replacing backslashes in MySQL 5 table seems to work: but how do I double check?

Tags: mysql, replace, escaping, quotes

I am trying to replace escaped quotes in a MySQL 5 table field, like this:

\' to '

\" to "

The query I'm using is:

```
UPDATE myTable SET content = REPLACE(content, '\\\'', '\'');
UPDATE myTable SET content = REPLACE(content, '\\\"', '\"');
```

Now it seems to work! What makes me wonder though is that it takes just 5 seconds on 70.000 entries in a 250 Megabyte table.

So is there a way to be sure or to double check?

Eddie

Comment: Note: 5 seconds to run that update is not particularly fast

Comment: Ok, didn't expect that. Do you think it's too slow? There are no indexes on this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just query for the thing you replaced to see if it's still there:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE content REGEXP "%\\\'%";
```

Comment: Thank you, did that, it helped. Sorry, I can't vote you up, I don't have enough reputation :-/